# Are System, console, Namespace classes or already instances?

Tags: c#, oop

I’m very new to programming. Actually less than one month back, I couldn’t name even 3 programming languages. So I’m really new to this.

After I understood the class concept and the object concept in OOP in general, I then realised that every single item present in the whole program is either an object or a class ready to give off objects.

Classes are non other than descriptions of objects, which are the main and sole players.

Moreover, functions or method are non other than sort of behavioural manifestation of an existing object.

( I wonder if the code line that we write for a function to be executed, the line of code in itself is a new object that refers to the existing original object that will perform the function we want , as part of its behaviour )

Now, If what I mentioned was near to be correct, What confused me next in my journey to understand OOP as a world wherein every single item is an object being utilised or destroyed, or brought into existence out of a class (blueprint ), which is nothing but a modifiable written description for objects how to be born.

What confused me here is the nature of “system”, “console”, and “namespace” each one of these, is it an object, so that we can call and utilise it without instantiating, or they are special classes readily instantiated as the program runs, or just ordinary classes ( which contradicts everything I understood ), because I can see "system" and "console" called and utilised only, and never instantiated ( just like an object )

Now, namespace seems to be a class that is instantiated into an object in the written script: ( namespace "the application name" {    } ) but neither "system" nor "console" seems to be instantiated by programmer!

Comment: OOP is not "just" classes and objects.  Keep researching, you'll get there!   (namespaces are not anything like classes.  They are a scoping mechanism  to deconflict name collisions.  (e.g. System.Console is entirely different from Physician.Console) ).

Comment: Thank you Sam, I'll keep researching, I think my vision was limited. After hours of reading I realise that my question was just unnecessary.

Thank for help anyhow Sam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System` is a [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx), `Console` is a [static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/79b3xss3.aspx) inside the namespace `System`.

Static classes are classes which do not need to be created with the `new` keyword, and there is only one instance per application (excluding templated static classes - which you don't need to worry about for the moment)

`Console` can be written like this:

```
namespace System { //Namespace defined here!
    public static class Console { //Static class defined here!
        public static void WriteLine() { //Static method defined here!
            //Implementation goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Note the keyword `static` when declaring the class. Removing this keyword would turn it into a normal class, and you'd have to use it like this:

```
var console = new System.Console();
console.WriteLine();
```

***Based on the comments from Bauss and Physician about static methods.***

You can write this, as well:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static void DoSomethingStatically()
    {

    }

    public void DoSomethingNormally()
    {

    }
}
```

Now, you can do this:

```
MyClass.DoSomethingStatically();
```

but you *cannot* do:

```
MyClass.DoSomethingNormally();
```

To use the second method, you must create an instance:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.DoSomethingNormally();
```

Note:

You cannot call a static method on an *instance*, so it is *invalid* to do the following:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.DoSomethingStatically();
```

Comment: You're partially correct. Removing `static` does not force you to create an instance of the class, if it has static members.

Comment: Thank you Rob for this answer,it clarifies what I wanted really.You wrote in the code: namespace System{}. While the System namespace is already an existing entity. Here I guess you're showing me what's already happening in the actual program, not something that I could or should do. Correct me if I'm wrong. Now the MainClass looks just not a static class, rather an ordinary class, while the main method is Static, Does it make the MainClass static as well, I guess not, But if so, is the MainClass it liable to instantiation. Thank you Rob, and thanks for mr Axe as well.

Comment: I'm really sorry guys that I ask these question, while it takes time and effort from yours to answer someone that doesn't look reading enough.

But I really have read a lot, and just got stuck in the major concepts for several days ago, and your answers just were extremely helpful to me, and your effort was very valuable.

Thanks guys indeed. wish you the best

Comment: @Physician "Here I guess you're showing me what's already happening in the actual program, not something that I could or should do" - That's right. Defining a namespace which already exists can cause *huge* problems, and if you were to put the code I posted into a file, you'd lose access to the built-in Console - which, while resolvable, is not ideal. As for the main class having a static method, as Bauss pointed out, methods *can* be static, while the class is not. This allows you selectively choose which methods require the `new` keyword. See my update for more info

Comment: @Physician And no need to apologise - we're happy to help someone out if it's clear they've spent time themselves trying to figure it out, which you clearly have done :)

Comment: Perfect explanation Rob. I really feel like I can go on and learn more now with a much clearer understanding. Really awesome, Just thanks man. you've helped a lot.. Best of luck

Comment: @Physician No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of namespaces as containers of classes. `System` is a namespace which contains the `Console` class. `Console` is a special kind of class called a *static class*. A static class is denoted by the `static` keyword. The `Console` class's declaration would look something like this:

```
namespace System {
    public static class Console {
        //lots of stuff...
    }
}
```

Actually you can read the `Console` class's source code in http://referencesource.microsoft.com

A static class cannot be instantiated. It just does its own work. It doesn't have objects. One of reasons is that it doesn't make sense to have objects. For example, the `Math` class is a static class because it doesn't make sense to say "Let's create a Math object!". Because Math is not like Cows or `Stream`s or `BinaryFormatter`s, which all are non static classes Generally, anything that you can prefix with "a" is not static. "a Stream", "a BinaryFormatter" etc.

Now for the namespace concept. You know sometimes the same word may mean different stuff depending on the context. e.g. Stream, in a programming context it means a file stream or some other kind of streams. But in a casual conversation, you say stream to mean a stream of water or something like that. So now you have to create two stream classes but there's a name conflict! That's why we have namespaces. Let's look at a real example. There are at least 2 classes called `Path`, but they are in different namespaces so it's ok to have the same name. One is in the `System.Drawing` namespace and the other is in the `System.IO` namespace. We often refer to those two classes as "System.IO.Path" and "System.Drawing.Path". Or you can write `using` directives.

Conclusion:

Both `System` and `Console` are *not* objects. They are a namespace and a static class respectively. And the word namespace denotes a namespace so it's not an object either.

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you indeed, Your answer just help me to re-establish my understanding of the concepts of OOP, yea really thank you.

Excuse me, would you explain to me why a namespace is't just replaced by yet another static class that will contain the rest of classes a namespace would normally contain, and we're done with same results, practically.

Yea I mean man if the answer doesn't require a lot of explanation from your side, because I think I should go re-read the whole subject from A to Z, after I understood what I struggled to.

That was awesome,thank you man indeed.

Comment: @Physician I guess it is because of the `using` directive. If they were all static classes, then the using directive can be `using Console;` which is a static class as well. But this doesn't make sense. So the folks at microsoft added a new keyword `namespace`. Well this is only my guess. If you want to know the truth, maybe go visit Microsoft or look at the C# language spec. By the way can you  accept my answer?

Comment: Yea I'd love to accept your answer it's awesome really,

however I'm afraid I then underestimate the answer of the guy above, which was just perfect for me. I would like to accept both answers if I could but it seems not allowed in the website. I'm really sorry, and thank you indeed, your answer is just as awesome, but honestly mr Rob answer helped me a bit more. Best of regard my brother. Hope you the best.